# REST communication between android applications, what to use?

Tags: android, spring, rest

I am building a distributed android application where communication is done both between a client and a server and between clients themselves. Communication between the client and server is done by using Spring framework on the client and nodejs with restify on the server.

But I am having some problems finding good ways to communicate between two android applications. I would like to have some sort of server on the client side, is Spring viable for this or should I just create a thread and use androids http library?

This is probably a vague question but I would like some feedback on how to implement this since it is difficult to find similar projects.

Edit: Thought about how applications like facebook messenger and other apps that needs Wi-Fi gets instant messages, how is that done? The apps need to run some kind of listener and the server needs to contact the clients, this is what I want to do except replace the server with another client.

Answer (score 2):

Running a server on an Android device is almost always a bad idea because it drains the battery and your ip address might change often. If you need device-to-device (android-to-android) communication, have a look at push notifications (you will need to route your messages through the server)
https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: This was my first thought and it would be both easier to implement and as you say better performance. But I am doing this project as part of a distributed systems course and our teacher demanded the system to be more distributed hence client/client communication.

Answer (score 0):

You should try [RoboSpice](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice). It's cool library that keeps network operations completely asynchronous. It supports many of the popular Android networking libraries like Spring and Retrofit.

Comment: So you recommend using Spring as a server on the application too? And RoboSpice to make asynchronous connections?

Comment: This is meant for the client/device that makes requests to the server. Robospice and it's plugins make it easy for that. In terms of running a server, that's beyond my skill set unfortunately.